# P2Pool - I get only rejects

Tags: bitcoin-core, p2pool

I started mining with P2Pool / cgminer.

bitcoin-qt.exe is running. run_p2pool.exe is running. cgminer is running.

But all I get are rejects.

What might be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean rejects? Are you asking why haven't you found any coins / blocks? If so, please edit your question and I'll undo my downvote.

Comment: His question makes sense to anyone with a clue about p2pool, which you apparently don't. Don't abuse downvotes just because you don't understand.

Comment: @Luke-Jr - if you mention my name with a `@`, I'll be notified of your comments. Downvote undone.

Answer (score 1):

This might mean your internet connection is too slow. With p2pool, you are basically competing against all the other miners for internet latency. If you have bandwidth-intensive software running (downloads, uploads) try stopping it.